# Custom fonts working in Interface Builder (Xcode 6), but not a device

Tags: ios8, interface-builder, xcode6

I added fonts by dragging and dropping in my projects, and I made sure that they are added to target.

I can use them in Interface Builder and they show correctly, however when I run it on a device or an emulator, it replaces it with system fonts.

I also added the fonts to `Info.plist` file, just to make sure even though I'm using iOS 8.1.

Any ideas what step am I missing, and why does it work perfect in Interface Builder, but not when compiled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using attributed string in IB then it will not work, it's a bug.

Comment: Yeah, it appears that there is a bug with attributed strings in IB. It works fine when I set it to plain text.